# How to use excluded delimiters in URI

Tags: java, http, url

I need to create a java URL object by providing a representation containing a delimiter, which is excluded for US_ASCII Characters. You can find the speicification here [2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

For example,

http://localhost:8182/a%image.tif

or

http://localhost:8182/a#image.tif

Does anybody know a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you encode the character? So # => %23 and % => %25. See more information on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Please do not refer to W3Schools. It is full of errors and misleading advices. See http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Well, fortunately this particular page wasn't in the list of errors ;-) In any case, thanks for the heads up. I wasn't aware of most of these errors, but that's probably because I've never visited most of those pages.

Comment: I'm afraid that particalar page is full of nonsense statements like "URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet" and errors such as confuisng proper URL encoding with the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME type.

Comment: Well, a better reference is probably wikipedia, but fortunately the two encodings in the table on W3Schools are correct :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a URI can be safely constructed only by encoding the individual components before assembling them into the final URI. In this case `a%image.gif` is a path component and must be encoded according the path production (3.3 in rfc 2369).

Use `java.net.URI` to create legal URI (and URLs):

```
    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8182/a%25image.gif");
    System.out.println(uri.toASCIIString());
    System.out.println(uri.getPath());
```

You should see the output of the last statement unencoded.

Technically, the second URL is not illegal, `image.gif`, would be treated as a fragment. But if the hash caharacter is part of the path, it must of course be encoded as well.